# Android Studio : E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

В чем ошибка?

```
    package by.belstu.somebody.simplechat;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;

import java.util.*;

public class UsersActivity extends Activity {

    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    private FirebaseUser user;

    private DatabaseReference db;
    private DatabaseReference users;

    private ArrayList<String> lUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> favorites = new ArrayList<>();

    private RecyclerView rView;
    private ModelAdapter rAdapter;

    private ArrayList<UserItem> usernames = new ArrayList<>();

    private String currentUser;

       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        user = auth.getCurrentUser();

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        users = db.child("users");

        rView = findViewById(R.id.rView);

        users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                lUsers.clear();
                favorites.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User usr = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    if (!user.getUid().equals(ds.getKey())) {
                        lUsers.add(usr.getUsername());
                    } else {
                        currentUser = usr.getUsername();
                        try {
                            favorites.addAll(usr.getFavorites());
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            Log.d("UsersActivity", "User does not have favorites");
                        }
                    }
                }

                usernames.clear();
                for (String usr: lUsers) {
                    usernames.add(new UserItem(usr, favorites.contains(usr)));
                }
                loadData();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void loadData() {
        rAdapter = new ModelAdapter(this, usernames, favorites, lUsers, currentUser, user.getUid(), users);
        rView.setAdapter(rAdapter);
        rView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Если у вас при этом всё работает - можете не обращать внимания. Если нет - напишите об этом в вопросе.

Comment: Это не является ошибкой, это больше предупреждение. Если у вас на макете страницы кроме `RV` больше ничего нет, и список не влияет на отображение других `View` - можете игнорировать это сообщение, т.к. оно лишь информирует что не смогло рассчитать нужный размер для `RV` в текущем макете. Поправьте если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Не работает , от главной активности перехожу на RV и пустой список , хотя данные есть , как исправить?